# Self-Sharpening Monomolecular Edge

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, weapons, materials, swords

In my research while trying to incorporate monomolecular edged blades in my story, i saw that a monomolecular edge would get instantly dull after cutting anything, but then i saw these depleted uranium armor piercing bullets that shed it's material and self-sharpens as it penetrates.

I wonder if it would be possible to implement this kind of property into a MME blade, something meant only for slashing soft tissue and not stabbing (like a karambit) so being brittle is not all of an issue.

And obviously the blades would need to be disposable because they would wear off insanely fast.

Comment: Why would you  say they'd need to be disposable - what's your conception of what a monomolecular blade looks like that it wouldn't be able to be sharpened or keep its edge in the first place?

Comment: Also please bear in mind that you've used 3 mutually exclusive tags at the same time and the scientific-development one doesn't seem to have any bearing at all. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance. I'll edit the tags for now, but you can re-edit later if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

1. You do not need them to be dull at use. You can make them sharp any time by puting some kind of electromagnetical field generators inside. If cutting edge is not iron/carbon/silicon/oxygen atom but electromagnetic field(arc) generated by sharp edge then no wear will be generated.
2. Rebuild edge. Need some kind of souce of edge material and pump it trough one atom wide gap.
3. Same as 2 but no pump only squishing blade sideways force material to go out by gap.

Answer (score 2):

**Cheese wire.**

[image: cheese wire]

Of course here the wire is the monomolecular filament.  There is no such thing as "dulling" a monomolecular filament.  How can it get less sharp than the single molecule it is made of?

But the wire can break.  When it does, the device can tell because there is a break in the circuit.  I imagine one hub slides across to the other side, carrying the fresh wire with it.  Fresh wires are stored within the device.  There are plenty.